# removing all instances of a string that is not within parantheses

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to remove all appearances of the string "J." from a longer string, but only where J. is not within parentheses:

Start:

```
text = "This is J. one instance and J. another (this one should stay J.) but this one should go J. (and stay J.) (and stay J. and stay J.) and go J."
```

End with:

```
"This is one instance and another (this one should stay J.) but this one should go (and stay J.) (and stay J. and stay J.) and go"
```

I've managed to achieve some of this through this gsub combination:

```
gsub("\\)[^(]+J.", ")", gsub("^[^(]+J.", "", text))
[1] " another (this one should stay J.) (and stay J.) (and stay J. and stay J.)"
```

But ideally I'd be able to keep the text outside the () besides the J.s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `base R`, we could use `*SKIP`, `*FAIL` to skip the matches within the parens

```
gsub("(\\([^\\)]*J\\.)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\s*J\\.", "", text, perl = TRUE)
```

-output

```
[1] "This is one instance and another (this one should stay J.) but this one should go (and stay J.) (and stay J. and stay J.) and go"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, casting to `tibble` and grouping by `(` and `)`

```
library(dplyr) # < dplyr 1.1.0 use summarize instead reframe

tibble(t = unlist(strsplit(text, " "))) %>% 
  mutate(beg = grepl("\\(", t), end = grepl("\\)", lag(t))) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(beg|end)) %>% 
  mutate(is = !grepl("\\(", t[1])) %>% 
  reframe(text = if_else(is, sub("J\\.", "", t), t)) %>% 
  filter(text != "") %>% 
  select(-grp) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  paste(collapse=" ")
[1] "This is one instance and another (this one should stay J.) but this one should go (and stay J.) (and stay J. and stay J.) and go"
```